# How does Python differentiate between static and instance attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I see a python class defined like

```
class Apple():
    count = 0
```

I see `count` to be a static attribute associated with `Apple` that can be accessed when writing `Apple.count`.

I came across an interesting example in one of my courses that doesn't disprove the above, but instead adds some ambiguity:

```
class Apple():
    count = None 
    def __init__(self, count):
      Apple.count = count

    def get_count(self):
      return self.count
```

Here, `count` is defined like a static attribute, and it is even assigned like one. In fact, it is a static attribute! However, it is returned via `self.count` which to me opposes the typical nature of the python nature. I would expect an error here to tell me that my instance of `Apple` has no attribute `count`, because if I run:

```
a = Apple(6)
b = Apple(8)
print(a.get_count(), b.get_count())
# 8 8
```

We can see that `get_count()` is actually returning the static attribute value `count` accessed through `Apple.count`.

My question is, why does python work this way? I always thought that `self` was tied to a particular instance of the class, but this behavior suggests that `self.count` is *identical* to `Apple.count` unless `self.count` is shadowed by writing `self.count = 10` or some other value. Is there any value to this behaviour in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case here:

```py
class Apple():
    count = None 
    def __init__(self, count):
      Apple.count = count

    def get_count(self):
      return self.count
```

`count` is declared as a `class` attribute, however the `__init__()` overwrites this each time an instance is created. You have seen that the last created instance sets the value for all instances

Another thing about `class` attributes is that they are visible when accessing like: `return self.count`.

However, if you also had this method:

```py
    def set_count(self, value):
        self.count = value
```

then each instance will get their own attribute `count` but only when this is called on that instance.

There is a value to this if you want instances to be initialised with the *same* value and it is extremely rare for any instance to need a different value, then the `class` attribute is set once when the class is compiled. Compare this with an `__init__()` setting `Apple.count = 0` for every instance. This could slow down your program and worse, if you did `self.count = 0`, would take up lots of space when you start creating millions of instances.